# SSRS only apply parameters to certain fields or exclude LookUp/Expressions?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report, lookup, ssrs-expression

I have a report that displays `employeeID`, `employeeEmail`, `supervisorID`, and `expirationDate`. I then use this LookUp function to find the supervisor email:

```
=Lookup(Fields!supervisorID.Value, Fields!employeeID.Value, Fields!employeeEmail.Value, "DataSet1")
```

The problem occurs when I set parameters for specific date ranges on the `expirationDate`

```
       expirationDate >=@startdate 
   AND expirationDate <=@enddate
```

This narrows the search result to only show employees with an expiration date in the date range. However, it also filters out my supervisor email address if the supervisors `expirationDate` doesn't fall within the range as well.

I don't want the LookUp expression to be subjected to the parameters of the date range. I want the supervisor email to **always** show. Because the date range parameter is meant to filter out the employees by expiration date, not the supervisors.

So when the employee is displayed because their `expirationDate` is in the range, their `supervisorID` should always be displayed, but because the LookUp expression then re-queries the dataset to find the email, the results are being blocked when the `expirationDate` isn't in the range for supervisors too.

Is there a way to exclude my LookUp/Expression from the parameters? Or for the parameters to only filter out specific column fields?

Answer (score 0):

So you're filtering "DataSet1" on the Dates too? You should just be able to remove that filtering so that the dataset contains all the email addresses available to be looked up. This won't affect which supervisors are shown in the report since presumably the content is coming from a different dataset than DataSet1 and that's why you're using lookup!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you specifiying the date range filter? If it's on the dataset then there is no way for the lookup function to reference rows that are not included in the dataset. One possibility is to add the date filter to the *table* (or whatever data region you're using), thus leaving all rows in the dataset to be referenced by the lookup function. This is an ok solution for small data sets but obviously doesn't scale well if the unfiltered dataset is very large.

A better solution in general would be to retrieve the supervisor details for each row in your dataset, by editing the query to do the join between employee and supervisor. This will be more efficient and you can then filter the dataset on employee dates and forget the lookup function, which means less work for your report to do.

Comment: What I ended up doing as work around is using a subreport. In the subreport, I list all employeeID's and employeeEmail's. Then when I pass the subreport back to the mainreport I only display the emails where supervisorID on mainreport matches employeeID from the subreport. I tried looking up how to join the fields in the query but couldn't figure it out I guess, searching for that though led to me finding out about subreports though, so thank you for the idea, it got me unstuck and looking at it a different way to come up with the same result.

Comment: Good to hear you were able to find a solution that worked for you Jeff

Comment: For future reference, assuming you had a source table of "Employee", with columns for EmployeeID, EmployeeEmail and SupervisorID you could write query like:        SELECT emp1.EmployeeID, emp1.EmployeeEmail, emp1.SupervisorID, emp2.EmployeeEmail AS SupervisorEmail FROM Employee emp1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee emp2 ON emp1.SupervisorID = emp2.EmployeeID                   - this gives you all the columns you need in one dataset. Joining a table back to itself like this is called a self referential join and is common when working with hierarchical data (such as supervisor - employee relationships).